# php - regex- preg_replace - space after line-break!

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, space, line-breaks

still on regex! i want learn it but i'm still crashing the head into my keybord! ;-)

ok very trivial for you, i'm sure!

Assuming i have this sting, the `\s` is where the space actualy is... `\n` where linebreak is..

**EDITED:**

```
   OTHERFIELD: Other text here...`\n`
   DESCRIPTION: The quick brown fox jum`\s\n`
   `\s`ps over the lazy dog
   OTHERFIELD: Other text here...`\n`
```

---

just for explanation:

each line always start with an UPPERCASE word followed by a colon!

so the only way i have for split each line is by it's last `\n` for this reason i can't remove it!

then i'm preg_splitting each cleaned line with this regex

```
/$\R?[^A-Z:]*/m
```

that give me an array like this:

```
[DESCRIPTION] => The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

---

now, what i need to do is remove All the space after the `A-Z:`

that i have achieved by this regex: `/\s+(?![A-Z:])/m` that produce this result

```
DESCRIPTION: The quick brown fox jum ps over the lazy dog
```

as you can see it leave the space between `jum` and `ps`

how to have a result like this?

```
DESCRIPTION: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

thank's for the time!

Comment: Can you write some of your actual code? I don't quite understand what you are doing with your regex. I also don't understand your goal. A-Z is capital letters only and you're using a negative lookahead expression?

Comment: ok let me do it just a second

Comment: i tried to explane, hope this make sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/\s+\n\s+/
```

This will match the whitespace only if it’s surrounding a line feed character. You may need to adjust the quantifiers to fit your actual data.

Comment: I think he might need to use the /s modifier (treat string as a single line) to make that work.

Comment: thank's for responce Gumbo, i  have tried your regex but unfortunely it don't work, i have updated my question, for better explane!

Comment: Why this doesn't work? You need to apply this regexp at the very beginning, before you split your text into lines.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: The *s* modifier will only make the `.` to also match line break characters. So `/.*/` matches just a single line while `/.*/s` matches all lines.

Comment: I used this to delete the white space in the beginning of every line: `$sql = preg_replace('/\n\s+/', "\n", $sql);` Thanks!